# C# Process arguments doesn't work with "<" and ">"

Tags: c#, process, arguments

I want to run a process in c#, but I have some problem with the "<", ">" signs in the arguments. I have tried like this >, but it doesn't help.

Here is the code:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"< \"{imagePath}\" > \"{optimizedImagePath}\"";
```

Comment: So what happens compared with what you *want* to happen? My guess is that you're expecting this to perform redirection - in which case you either need to set UseShellExecute to true or if that doesn't work (I can't remember offhand whether it should or not) you should launch cmd.exe with appropriate arguments.

Comment: < and > are reserved operators.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect using the < and > signs as arguments in C#
To do this you'll have to use the `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` and  `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput` to manually read the file stream and redirect it in and out of the process.

Try something like this: (Untested!)

```
Image imageIn = new Image("imagepath.jpg");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);

process.StandardInput.Write(ms.ToArray());
```

Comment: Could you write some sample code? I would really appreciate it!